# UIViewController equivalent of SKView's update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) method

Tags: swift, uikit

I was wondering what the best way to replicate the update method from the SKView in a UIViewController is? I couldn't find any native methods within the class, but I might have overlooked something.

I am trying to make a game using UIKit where items move across the screen continuously.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewController` is designed differently than `SKView`, and does not have an internal timer that evaluates per frame that you can just tie into.  You would need to setup some kind of repeating timer (i.e., `CADisplayLink` or `Timer`) to manually move views around.  Alternatively you could look into repeating animations (keyframe animations perhaps), but in my experience depending on how you do this hit testing can be problematic.